# cmd type without printing filenames

Tags: windows, cmd, concatenation

I have a makefile that concatenates two files to create a small kernel.
I am using the following command:

```
type boot_sect.bin kernel.bin > os-image
```

Unfortunately, type still shows something on the cmd:

```
boot_sect.bin



kernel.bin
```

Is there a way to not show the filenames with type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following command:

```
copy /y /b boot_sect.bin+kernel.bin os-image > nul
```

The `/y` switch is to automatically overwrite the destination file in case it already exists and `/b` is for binary copy.